# Create an empty list for each item in a list

Tags: python

I have a list that came from an excel doc:

```
["GT", "FSU", "Duke"]
```

I am trying to make an empty list for each item in this list (to look like this):

```
GTList = []
FSUList = []
Duke = []
```

Is there an easy way to go from step 1 to step 2. I need to use loops too because there is a possibility of there being an extra school in the first list. If this is the case, there needs to be a corresponding empty list for that new school. Please let me know what advice you have.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a dictionary comprehension:

```
schools = ["GT", "FSU", "Duke", "Stanford"]

schools_list = {school: [] for school in schools}

>>> schools_list
{'Duke': [], 'FSU': [], 'GT': [], 'Stanford': []}

schools_list['Stanford'].append('sucks')
>>> schools_list['Stanford']
['sucks']
```

Comment: LOL at Stanford value

Comment: Thanks man. For me it would be more fitting to throw UGA in Stanford's place

Comment: @CalebRudnicki remember that you can accept an answer if it solved your question.

Answer (score 0):

I [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33174893/how-to-assign-a-string-value-as-an-empty-dictionary-in-python/33175378#33175378) similar question earlier today. Try this:

```
a = ["GT", "FSU", "Duke"]

for i in a:
    locals()[i] = []

print GT, FSU, Duke
```

Output:

> [ ] [ ] [ ]

[Demo](http://ideone.com/EXBQbm).

Also, [here's](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/05/why-you-dont-want-to-dynamically-create.html) why you shoudn't be creating dynamic variables which is why I recommend Alexander's answer

Comment: It says "global name 'GT' is not defined

Comment: Yes, I'm curious as well.  @sam2090 answered the OP's question, and then explained that this is not what you want to do.

Comment: @Alexander I guess someone didn't like my stanford comment :)